# what are recommendation for pod size(CPU, memory) in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, azure-aks, amazon-eks, kubernetes-pod

I want to know the recommendation set for pod size. I.e. when to put application within pod or at what size it will be better to use machine itself in place of pod.

Ex. when to think of coming out of k8s and used as external service for some application, when pod required 8GB or 16GB or 32GB? Same for CPU intensive.

Because if pod required 16GB or 16 CPU and we have a machine/node of the same size then I think there is no sense of running pod on that machine. If we run in that scenario then it will be like we will having 10 pods and which required 8 Nodes.

Hopes you understand my concern.

So if some one have some recommendation for that then please share your thoughts on that. Some references will be more better.

Recommendation for ideal range:

1. size of pods in terms of RAM and CPU
2. Pods is to nodes ratio, i.e. number of pods per nodes
3. Whether good for stateless or stateful or both type of application or not

etc.

Comment: think\read why microservices are called microservices. monolithic application days are long gone ;)

Comment: @4c74356b41. Thanks for the comment. Can you share your view on microservice vs monolithic. As in my thoughts microservice should be like lots of stateless container of small size of a application in place of one large container in the environment. As this provide us both reliability and fault tolerance, which is advantage of microservices.

Comment: @PrakulSinghal were you able to decide on the ideal size for your POD?

Answer (score 4):

Running 16cpu/16gb pod on 16cpu/16gb machine is normal. Why not? You think of pods to be tiny but there is no such requirement. Pods can be gigantic, there is no issue with that. Remember container is just a process on a node, why you refuse to run a fat process on a fat node? Kubernetes adds very nice orchestration level to containers, why not make use of it?

There is no such thing as a universal or recommended pod size. Asking for recommended pod size is the same as asking for a recommended size for VM or bare metal server. It is totally up to your application. If your application requires 16 or 64 GB of RAM - this is the recommended size for you, you see?

Regarding pods to nodes ratio - current upper limit of Kubernetes is 110 pods per node. Everything below that watermark is fine. The only thing is that recommended master node size increases with total number of pods. If you have like 1000 pods - you go with small to medium size master nodes. If you have over 10 000 pods - you should increase your master nodes size.

Regarding statefulness - stateless application generally survive better. But often state also should be stored somewhere and stored reliably. So if you plan your application as a set of microservices - create as much stateless apps you can and as few stateful as you can. Ideally, only the relational databases should be truly stateful.

Comment: Thanks Vasily Angapov for the explaination.

Comment: Will do that later, but currently waiting for others to communicate the same or if I found some references for the same too. As with your vast experience in the field of containerization I am sure big fatty pod are not an issue. But still somewhere in my mind it fighting that microservice should be as 10s or 100s of small pods of an application in place of one fatty pod.

Comment: well, it is not necessarily that you need to run fat pods from the very beginning. Initially when an application is not so much used - you can go with 0.5 cpu 0.5 gb ram. That can easily be called microservice, right? Because it's small. But when you place app into production and real people start using it - you quickly understand that you need to increase resources dramatically. Even if you have multiple replicas - still each replica sometimes just has to be big enough to do real world tasks. And then you have some doubts - is it a microservice really?

Comment: We see large pods when working with modernized applications. A monolith, Java WAR file that is now running in a container pod.